# Platform cache increasing visualforce execution time

Tags: apex, visualforce, platform-cache

I have decided to use platform cache to retain the result of an expensive callout and processing. Doing so eliminated the callout time and shaved 500ms off of the apex time. Unfortunately my gains were partially eliminated by the visualforce time jumping from ~180ms to more than 600ms. Is this a bug or is there something I need to do to stop this behavior?

Comment: Not entirely surprising. You might get better performance by trying to cache the results in a custom setting instead.

Comment: No can do @AdrianLarson, it is a pretty large chunk of data and custom settings only allow 255 characters in a single field.

Comment: Well, the bright side is you saved 80ms.

Comment: Custom Metadata is another option, long text fields now supported; Winter 18 allows Apex to write to custom metadata